# Fancybox iframe content - how to access CSS from parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I am opening a [Fancybox](http://Fancybox.net) iframe from within a page that has several stylesheets loaded.

The content in the iframe is from my own app, but it is not taking the stylesheets from the parent.

Is there a way of doing this without having to load the stylesheets all over again in the iframe page itself?

Comment: Similar Q/A here, try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583753/using-css-to-affect-div-style-inside-iframe

Comment: Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612374/iframe-inherit-from-parent. Make sure you read the comments on the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks guys very helpful - sorry for the dupe, i ended doing my search  using `fancybox` instead of more generic terms :P

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. If you load the content inline rather than in an iframe, the content will be in the parent and have its styles.

Otherwise... I don't think so.