# How can apply css to externally loading web page using iframe. Is it possible?

Tags: css, iframe, web, external

I would like to add a page(a market watch ticker) from other website which is given by client using iframe. but its color not matching my website. how to match it. is there any way to match it??please help?

Comment: no you can't change it

Comment: @btevfik..thats very sad:(

Comment: actually, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714880/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe-content

Comment: does it work? i didnt really try. you can search for other on google or here.

Comment: its not works..i think its not possible...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the iFrame to inherit the parents CSS and javascript see this question:

[Iframe inherit from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612374/iframe-inherit-from-parent)

But you need access to the iFrame markup to do this, otherwise I believe it is not possible (and probably shouldn't be for other reasons like security etc.)