# How to make iframe use css and javascript from the parent page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I am developing a portal using mvc5, on that portal I have a page that has an iframe elements such:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="mgArea">
    <iframe id="iframeMgMap" src="@(string.Format("../../mapData/infoMarko/?WEBLAYOUT={0}",Model.MgPath))"
                    frameborder="0"
                    scrolling="no"
                    style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

The portal and the Iframe's content is on the same IIS and runs on the same pool.

I added some css styles in the portal (like bootstrap.css, etc.) and some javascript libraries and plugins (like bootstrap.js and jquery).

My question -  is it possible to make iframe use the same css styles and javascript libraries and plugins from it's parent page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iframe inherit from parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612374/iframe-inherit-from-parent)

Answer (score 1):

My first question would be why you use an iframe. If you trust the code inside the `iframe` and you want to inherit css and js from the parent, why not use a normal `div` or other html element?

However, if you still have good reasons to use the iframe, you can access the parent by using `window.parent`.

Comment: Because I have to separate projects running on IIS.Is it possible to use enother HTML element in my case?

Answer (score 1):

You could include the "inner page" using the [html link tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp).

> The  tag defines a link between a document and an external resource.

See following example:

File **test.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="import" href="test2.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Main page</p>
        <p id="innerpage"></p>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    var content = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import;
    console.log(content);
    var inner = document.getElementById("innerpage");
    inner.append(content.body)
</script>
```

File **test2.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Test 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Test 2 page</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't make a fiddle cause the CORS limitation, anyway I've uploaded a working example [here](http://www.maglioccola.com/test/test.html).

I hope it helps you, bye.