# How disqus able inherit parent's styles?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, disqus

You can't inherit parent's properties into an iframe
Source: [Iframe inherit from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612374/iframe-inherit-from-parent).

But how come disqus able to inherit it's background color from parent? 
For example this site: https://kostasbariotis.com/geospatial-query-with-mongodb-and-node-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `<iframe>` is transparent.

Example:

```html
<div style="background-color:#000;">
    <iframe src="about:blank" allowtransparency="true" style="background-color: transparent;" />
</div>
```